# Tern JS for Vim using NVM

Tags: javascript, node.js, vim, nvm, tern

I'm trying to get [Tern JS](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim#installation) working in Vim on OSX 10.10.x.

I'm currently using NVM and as the Tern JS documentation states you can't use NVM.

> **Caution:** Because the node process is not run using your standard shell, >the NVM version of node.js won't work. You need a global node executable.

I'm not sure how to fix this. Do I need to install Node the "regular" way or is there a better way of solving this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set a default node version used in a new shell?

```
nvm alias default stable
```

I have no problem with `Tern JS for VIM` plugin